# Button click outside widget - GWT

Tags: java, gwt

Is it possible to detect when click event occurs outside a widget, i create a widget to display a text for a user, number of text varies for each user, and add it to my vertical panel. The user will be able to edit this text and also add new text.

Right now a text is locked from edit mode only if they click on a button, is it possible to skip this step and say if they click on the next text widget block the previous block is locked??

How can i read the action of moving to the next widget??

Comment: A [BlurHandler](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/FormItem.html#addBlurHandler(com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.events.BlurHandler)) will do. You will need to enable [`setDisabled(false)`] the text for next edit as well, probably after a save or similar operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That event is called as `blur event`. This event is triggered when widget loses its `focus`.

```
 textBox.addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
             //DO something
        }
 });
```